# How can we retrieve the intercom messenger user/contacts from the API?

Tags: intercom

I have a production website integrated with an intercom messenger, now I want to retrieve those users from the API, I am an access token followed this URL https://developers.intercom.com/building-apps/docs/authentication-types#section-how-to-get-your-access-token
App has the app owner access.

Now I try to retrieve the users with the API https://api.intercom.io/contacts for version 2.x.
Tried using version 1.x also https://api.intercom.io/users but do not get my live users!

Problems -

1. If I create a user from the API then I am able to retrieve it from the API, but cannot see it in the intercom Dashboard https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/xyz/users/segments/all-users.
2. Not able to retrieve the user who is there in the dashboard from API.

Can you suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing a silly mistake.

API
So little summary for the intercom -
It has 2 version -

1. 1.x -- which uses the user's concept
2. 2.x -- which uses the contact concept, in this version user, leads are replaced by contacts.

When you go to create your app and grab the access token make sure u pick up the correct one which has app owner access.
https://developers.intercom.com/building-apps/docs/authentication-types#section-how-to-get-your-access-token

When u call the API choose the correct version - https://developers.intercom.com/building-apps/docs/update-your-api-version#section-selecting-the-version-via-the-api-request